# Escaping shell_exec

Tags: php, escaping, shell-exec

I can run this:

```
echo shell_exec ("tail -n 500 /var/log/website.com_access_log | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -gr | head -10");
```

But I can't run this (works in terminal):

```
echo shell_exec ("tail -n 500 /var/log/website.com_access_log | sed -e 's/^\([[:digit:]\.]*\).*\"\(.*\)\"$/\1 \2/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -gr | head -10");
```

returns nothing or "500  " (gibberish here)

Obviously, it has something to do with escaping. Only `"` are escaped for PHP in example.
I tried `escapeshellarg()` and `escapeshellcmd()` without success (returns nothing). A also tested escaping \ with `\\, \\\, \\\\`.

What is wrong here? What should I escape?

Comment: Maybe create a bash script that made this command line and call this script with `shell_exec()` should be more easier?

Comment: Sounds right, thanks. I'll do it if there is no solution.

Comment: Also why not use single quotes to wrap the cmd then you only goto escape the 2 inside which wont effect your regex.

Comment: Sorry, @LawrenceCherone I haven't seen your comment. I could delete my anwser if you want to made yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using single quotes solve the problem. Also adding `:` in your first capture group allows to grab IPv6 addresses.

```
echo shell_exec ('tail -n 500 /var/log/website.com_access_log | sed -e \'s/^\([[:digit:]:\.]*\).*\"\(.*\)\"$/\1 \2/\' | sort | uniq -c | sort -gr | head -10');
```

Outputs :

```
474 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
 19 ::1 Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.xx (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.xxx.xxx Safari/xxx.xx
  7 ::1 Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.xx (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/64.0.xxx.xx Chrome/64.0.xxx.xxx Safari/xxx.xx
```

Comment: I always forget about this single/double quotes difference. Thanks for IPv6.

Comment: Btw, I was just messing with local logs (127.0.0.1), here is solution to not saving them https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/InternalDummyConnection

Comment: @Qiao Interesting. Thank you.